# What could be the source of various AVG "Exploits" (Rogue Scanner, Fake Video Player, Social Engineering, etc)?

Tags: exploit, antimalware

Recently, I've been getting 2-3 messages a day (usually at least 2 at a time) with AVG gleefully saying that they've protected me from one of these threats.

[image: Example AVG readout]

Clicking through to look at details, they don't seem to indicate which website triggered it. I don't think I've been viewing any pages horribly different than I have in the past, and I rack up these messages even when not actively browsing (I get knocked out of games with them, and while I was gone for three days, it racked up another 7-8 of them). It always says all items are resolved, but it still does not leave me with a good feeling. How do I determine what's causing the problem?

Comment: Because this is specific to a particular program, you might need to deal with their technical support.

Comment: Ah. Which looks to largely be community forums unless I get premium support. I will try there as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrote as a comment first, but it quickly grew up and didn't fit :(

Your verdict shows the website which triggered it - quickprivacycheck.com. Please see http://www.avgthreatlabs.com/us-en/virus-and-malware-information/info/rogue-scanner/ - note that quickprivacycheck.com website is reported as being the #1 site triggering this exploit in last 7 days.

If you don't visit this website yourself, and have no idea what it is, you need to find out which software on your computer visits this website. The possibilities are:

- You have some malware/adware installed - this could include software, browser plugins (especially browser toolbars), games etc;
- You receive emails with images referring to this website via  tag, and your e-mail client automatically loads the images (this is generally bad idea);
- A website you routinely visit is now infected. This is not unusual; you can scan it on virustotal.com (click on URL tab);
- A website you routinely visit shows content from a 3rd party website which is infected (ads, news, widgets). This happens more often than above, and [even major ad networks could serve malware](http://www.theverge.com/2014/9/19/6537511/google-ad-network-exposed-millions-of-computers-to-malware).

Finally, there is also a possibility that the website is clean, and the verdict is incorrect. This is called "false positive", and also happens once in a while. I do not see any verdict for quickprivacycheck.com in our database (disclamer: I work for Bitdefender), and the site main page returns an empty HTML file, so I can't analyze it. Still there's a possibility which should be accounted for.

Comment: They seem to have stopped. Unfortunately, running through your steps didn't provide any new insight on what the true source was (every website came out clean on the scanner, and I couldn't find any adware). I suspect that it was a matter of 3rd-party content triggering it. Thank you for your help.